# Moodle on AWS ECS

Tags: amazon-ecs, moodle

I am looking to host Moodle LMS on AWS ECS.
I have seen some resources like Bitnami's docker images for Moodle. But not sure if it's the best or the easiest option.
Is there any other good documentation or steps that I can follow to set it up?

Answer (score 0):

After you have created an aws account, login to your account:

1. Search for Ec2, under search results click on Ec2
   Create and then launch an Ec2 instance [recommendation: ubuntu]
   You are given public and private IP addresses, DNS.
2. An access key file [anyname.pem] file would be given, save that file because you would need it to connect to the FTP file manager client.
3. Wait for the instance state to show running, then connect to that EC2 instance;

Uploading Moodle files to ec2 file manager

1. Install FileZilla client, launch it
2. Go to Edit tab click on settings.
3. Under the settings box, select SFTP then upload that access key file downloaded from ec2, save and close that tab.
4. Then under host, put in your public IP address, enter username[ubuntu], enter port as 22, then quick connect.
5. When the file directory loads you need to set up apache virtual hosts.

Check this documentation to create apache virtual hosts:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-18-04-quickstart

After setting up the virtual hosts follow the Moodle docs for the step by step installation instructions for moodle

Answer (score 0):

Deploying Moodle to ECS is very different from deploying it on a simple EC2 instance so Moodle's official installation guide won't help with the clouding part.

I can't recommend a source for the container you need to use as I'm also researching the same topic but [the article here](https://medium.com/prismcloud-tech/moodle-on-aws-a-cloud-native-approach-part-1-3a0e68582024) seems like a good start.

Answer (score -1):

The Moodle docs provide full step-by-step installation instructions for Moodle on Ubuntu. This covers all standard dependencies. You can find the instructions here:

- https://docs.moodle.org/310/en/Step-by-step_Installation_Guide_for_Ubuntu

Otherwise, you can certainly use third party images such as Bitnami's docker images, but obviously the instructions for getting those working, and maintaining them going forward, would need to come from the organisation providing the image.